# Attempted to send a bulk request to elasticsearch' but Elasticsearch appears to be unreachable or down

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to push data from logstash to AWS ES and getting below error. Could anyone please me to fix this.

[2019-01-04T08:52:50,757][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to send a bulk request to elasticsearch' but Elasticsearch appears to be unreachable or down! {:error_message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://search-mb-production-app-.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:80/][Manticore::SocketTimeout] Read timed out", :class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError", :will_retry_in_seconds=>64}
[2019-01-04T08:52:53,345][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://search-mb-production-app-**.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:80/"}

Comment: Did you check if your es is up and reachable from your application computer?

Comment: Yes aws es is up and reachable

Comment: Where is logstash running? Does the server running logstash allowed access to communicate with AWS ES domain? Check ES access policy

Comment: Logstash running on EC2 instance , Yes I logstash has AWS ES access. And even logstash and AWS ES working fine . Suddenly I am getting this error